# Banner bootstrap con 2 imagenes responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, web

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[1]:

```
<!-- Banner -->
<section class="banner">
    <div class="container-fluid banner__container" >
        <div class="row banner__row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 banner__paragraphs">
                <div class="paragraphs__container">
                    <h1 class="m-4 hero-heading paragraphs__title m-0">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet </h1>
                    <h2 class="m-4 paragraphs__subtitle">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h2>
                </div>
                <button class="ml-4 paragraphs__button shadow btn btn-secondary">Primary</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 banner__media">
                <div class="banner__images">
                    <div class="images__phone"></div>
                    <div class="images__capture"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
```

/*css*/

```
/*banner */


/* Height control */
.banner {
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 0;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: rgb(2, 117, 216);
}

.banner__container,
.banner__row {
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* --- paragraphs --- */

.paragraphs__subtitle {
    font-size: 'Open Sans';
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.banner__paragraphs {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    color: white;
}

.paragraphs__title,
.paragraphs__subtitle {
    text-align: center;
}

/* --- media ---*/

.banner__media {
    min-height: 530px;
    padding: 0; /* rid bootstrap padding*/
    width: 100%;

}

.banner__images {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images__phone {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 200;
    height: 130%;
    width: 100%;

    background-image: url('../images/iphone.png');
    background-size: cover;
    animation-name: slideInUp;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

.images__capture {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 135%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/admin.png');
    background-size: cover;
    animation-name: slideInUp;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

.images__phone,
.images__capture {
    top: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {

    .images__phone,
    .images__capture {
        left: 20vw;
    }


}

@media (min-width: 800px) {

    .images__phone,
    .images__capture {
        left: 30vw;
    }


}


@media (min-width: 992px) {

    .banner {
        margin-top: 60px;
        max-height: calc(100vh - 60px)
    }

    .banner__paragraphs,
    .banner__media {
        max-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
    }

    .paragraphs__title,
    .paragraphs__subtitle {
        text-align: left;
    }

    .images__capture {
        height: 130%;
    }

    .images__phone,
    .images__capture {
        top: 25px;
        left: 0;
    }

    .banner__paragraphs {
        align-items: flex-start;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {

    .images__capture {
        height: 135%;
    }

    .images__capture,
    .images__phone {
        left: 10%;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    .images__capture,
    .images__phone {
        left: 20%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .images__capture,
    .images__phone {
        left: 40%;
    }
    .paragraphs__title,
    .paragraphs__subtitle {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
}
/*banner*/
```

hay un problema que en otras resoluciones los elementos de la imagen del capture y del celular se mueven y siempre deberian mantener esa proporcion y posicion en cualquier resolucion, y en movil las imageenes se deberian desplazar hacia abajo pero en la misma posicion. y justo hasta el boton azul.

pd: el *banner* siempre debe ocupar la totalidad del *height* en diferentes monitores, y obvio que se ajuste el texto y las imágenes a esa resolución, pero en vez de eso, se achica el texto, las imágenes se achican o se mueven un poco hacia arriba.

no se que mas hacer :(, quizás como un amigo dice, con *javascript* se solucionaría, pero no soy muy diestro en js.

eso sin contar que tampoco puedo integrar **midnight.js** en esta pagina web para que cambie el color del nav y el color de texto e icono.

please , help!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar javascript para tal situacion o jquery, en mi opinion resulta mas practico y facil aqui te dejo un ejemplo :

**esta es la sintaxys para javascript**

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 820) { /*altura mayor o igual a x cantida tu codigo a ejecutar */ }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1280) { /*anchura mayor o igual a x cantida tu codigo a ejecutar */ }
}
```

**sintaxys jquery**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.height() >= 820) { /*altura mayor o igual a x cantida tu codigo a ejecutar */ }
      if (win.width() >= 1280) { /*anchura mayor o igual a x cantida tu codigo a ejecutar */ }
});
```

Comment: Gracias andy. dentro de los corchetes colocaria un el css que se deberia ejecutar, tipo media query?. no soy muy diestro en JQuery ni js, pero seria algo asi? , 'height':'900px', o asi?, $('#banner').css({ 'height':'900px' }); y asi $('.images_phone,images_capture').css({ 'top':'30px' }); algo asi?.

Comment: exactamente amigo ! si te sirvio la respuesta no olvides calificarla como valida gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>


    Alto=$(window).height();
    Ancho=$(window).width();
    AltoX=Alto-64;
    AltoY=Alto-(Alto/3);
    $(".text_content").css({"height":AltoX+"px"});
    $(".dispositivos").css({"height":AltoY+"px"});

//banner
if (Alto>780 && Alto<820 ) {    
    if (Ancho>1200 && Ancho <1300) {
        $(".text_content").css({"width":"40%"});
        $(".dispositivos").css({"width":"57%"});        
    }

    if (Ancho>340 && Ancho < 390) {
        $(".banner").css({"min-height":"1200px"});
        $(".banner .text_content").css({"height":Alto+"px"});
        $(".banner .text_content").css({"min-height":Alto+"px"});

        $(".banner .dispositivos").css({"height":(1200-Alto)+"px"});
        $(".banner .dispositivos").css({"min-height":(1200-Alto)+"px"});

    }
}


</script>
```